# Automatic select Update or delete on Ruby on Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I display items on a cart for the user on the form:  2 x item1, for example. I want to have a link beside where the use clicks to decrease the quantity of item1. If the quantity is 1, the register is deleted. With one link, how can I choose between update and delete?

I tried just creating the link to update and in the logic on update action, depending on the value of quantity, update the register or redirect_to destroy but, it doesn't work. This is the  instruction:

redirect_to delete_line_item_path(:id => params[:id]), method: :delete, :class => 'delete_book'

When I try to execute delete, I receive the following error:

undefined method `delete_line_item_path' for #

I also tried creating a helper, calling the helper from the link, so that the helper would make the decision of returning either the string or update or destroy but, it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not change the button to hit delete.  Instead, keep hitting the update action and put an after_update callback on the line_item to delete itself if the count goes to 0.

By the way, there is no `delete_line_item_path` method.  There is a `line_item_path` method that generates the right url - the http method: (delete | put) will determine if it goes to the destroy or update action.